# Using UICollection View with custom Cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ios8, uicollectionviewcell

I want to use collectionview and for that I have created a custom collectionviewcell. But when I access any element of the cell it turned out to be nil and it does not get assigned the values I give to them.

For example:
I have a cell in which I have a label. When I do:

```
cell.nameLabel?.text = contact.objectAtIndex(0) as String
```

It does not get assigned to that value. And if remove the optional thing the application crashes with error "Found nil while unwrapping the option value"

This is how I am setting up the collection view:

```
self.contactsCollection.tag = 112
        self.contactsCollection.registerClass(CollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
        self.flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
        self.flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2.0
        self.flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 2.0
        self.contactsCollection.pagingEnabled = true
        self.contactsCollection.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        self.contactsCollection.collectionViewLayout = self.flowLayout
```

And rest are the normal delegate methods for the collectionView.

My problem is that why the label is coming nil and the value I am assigning is not get assigned to the label?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created a prototype cell in the storyboard, remove `self.contactsCollection.registerClass(CollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")`

By calling this, I believe the prototype in the storyboard is overridden, which is why the label is nil.

Comment: I am not using storyboards.

Comment: Will you please update your question with the custom collectionviewcell code and the code in collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)?

Answer (score 0):

Use instead

```
register(nib: UINib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier)
```

the code would be

```
self.contactsCollection.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing: CollectionCell.self), bundle: Bundle(for: CollectionCell.self)), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
```

the file has to be called exactly, CollectionCell.xib